# How to test an AWS Glue streaming job that reads from a Kinesis stream locally

Tags: pyspark, aws-glue, amazon-kinesis

I'm using CDK to create an application that utilizes AWS Glue Streaming jobs to read from a Kinesis stream and then writes the data into a (Iceberg) table.
The important bit is, that Glue uses Spark to read from the stream and process batches (see GlueContext`).
I will post some code below if it helps.

What I need to know, and I hope some experts here can help me, is how to test the setup locally, without accessing the original AWS resources. I could, of course, use existing AWS resources for testing, but that involves costs and I would prefer to avoid that.

I know there is a docker container that allows running Glue jobs locally, found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-libraries.html#develop-local-docker-image). But how can I provide (mock) data that is read by the Spark code?

I found and checked tools like localstack, kinesalite, kinesis-local. Only localstack seem to be a valid option, but I fail to utilize it in the Spark code...

The following PySpark code is to show how the stream is actually handled.

```
sc = SparkContext()
gc = GlueContext(sc)
spark = gc.spark_session
job = Job(gc)

def processBatch(data_frame, batchId):
    if (data_frame.count() > 0):
        dynamic_frame = DynamicFrame.fromDF(data_frame, gc, "from_data_frame")

        # dynamic_frame.printSchema()

        # Write to S3 Sink
        gc.write_data_frame.from_catalog(
            frame=dynamic_frame,
            database=args["database_name"],
            table_name=args["table_name"]
        )

# Read from Kinesis Data Stream
sourceData = gc.create_data_frame.from_catalog(
    database = args["database_name"],
    table_name = args["table_name"],
    additional_options = {"startingPosition": args["starting_position_of_kinesis_iterator"], "inferSchema": "true"})

# sourceData.printSchema()

gc.forEachBatch(frame = sourceData, batch_function = processBatch, options = {"windowSize": "100 seconds", "checkpoint_location": checkpoint_location})
job.commit()
```

Alternatively, it is possible to read Kinesis streams like this.

```
kinesis_options =
   { "streamARN": "arn:aws:kinesis:us-east-2:777788889999:stream/fromOptionsStream",
     "startingPosition": "TRIM_HORIZON", 
     "inferSchema": "true", 
     "classification": "json" 
   }
data_frame_datasource0 = gc.create_data_frame.from_options(connection_type="kinesis", connection_options=kinesis_options)
```